# SQL query i have two tables here the first table name is ward and the second is patient

Tags: mysql, sql

the query is: Get the ward numbers and ward names for all wards that have no patients

[image]

I have tried

```
select ward.ward_no , ward.ward_name 
from ward , patient 
where ward.ward_no != patient.ward_no
```

Comment: Have you even tried to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service** ___Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not code things for you___

Comment: Please post your effort and we'll be here to fix that for you!

Comment: yes but get all wards not the ward that have no patients

Comment: yes but you have to try to do something for yourself. _Have a wild guess or maybe look at a book or tutorial_

Comment: my query is : select ward.ward_no , ward.ward_name from ward , patient where ward.ward_no != patient.ward_no

Comment: Well thats better than nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ward_no, ward_name
FROM ward
WHERE ward_no NOT IN (
  SELECT ward_no
  FROM patient
);
```

This is just one way to do it.
Does this answer your question?